Skipping dictionaries that contain certain keys
I'm looking for a good way to skip dictionaries that contain certain keys among multiple dictionaries that are different.
Right now I'm chaining .get() methods on a dictionary object and continuing on whatever matches, which is working but its kinda messy.
I'm doing something like:
...
if my_dict.get('some_key', my_dict.get('other_key', my_dict.get('some_other_key'))):
    continue



You can use any with a generator expression that iterates over the possible keys and tests if the dict has any of the keys:
if any(key in my_dict for key in ('some_key', 'other_key', 'some_other_key')):
    continue

Alternatively, you can use set.isdisjoint to test if the set of keys is disjoint with the dict keys:
if not {'some_key', 'other_key', 'some_other_key'}.isdisjoint(my_dict):
    continue

And as @deceze points out, you can also simply test if the set of keys intersects with the set of dict keys, which looks more readable:
if {'some_key', 'other_key', 'some_other_key'}.intersection(my_dict):
    continue

But be aware that unlike set.isdisjoint, set.intersection creates a new set and does not short-circuit on the first match, so is more expensive both time and space-wise.

Instead of a double negative not isdisjoint, just intersection would make more sense.

@deceze intersection doesn't short-circuit.

Maybe so, but that's quite the micro optimisation vs. more comprehensible code IMO.

It also unnecessarily creates a new set. But sure, I can add intersection as a note.

Looks like OP is trying to check the truthiness of the values of those keys, and not the presence of the keys themselves.
This answer seems to be proposing the later.
You'll have to change it to if any(my_dict[key] for key in (....))
Alternatively, consider the second answer submitted using map and any

@DarshanAS Judging by the wording "contain" in the OP's description of the goal, "to skip dictionaries that contain certain keys", I believe it's the presence of certain keys that the OP actually wants to test. The OP's code using dict.get happens to work only because there is no dict that contains falsey values.

@bihsing Ah, you might be right. OP's description of the problem and the code snippet are different. I missed the description part while answering.
